# Error unknown type name 'constexpr' during make in mac os x

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

when i make some program in using scons, there happen error like,

> error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
>
> error: expected unqualified-id

I'm already installed xcode and xquartz latest version.
this is my mac clang version

> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

And, i attached my whole error log just in case.

```
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:54:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double     pi  = 3.1415;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:54:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double     pi  = 3.1415;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:55:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double  twopi  = 2*pi;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:55:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double  twopi  = 2*pi;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:56:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double halfpi  = pi/2;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:56:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double halfpi  = pi/2;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:57:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double     pi2 = pi*pi;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:57:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double     pi2 = pi*pi;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:62:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double millimeter  = 1.;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:62:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double millimeter  = 1.;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:63:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double millimeter2 = millimeter*millimeter;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:63:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double millimeter2 = millimeter*millimeter;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:64:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double millimeter3 = millimeter*millimeter*millimeter;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:64:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double millimeter3 = millimeter*millimeter*millimeter;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:66:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double centimeter  = 10.*millimeter;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:66:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double centimeter  = 10.*millimeter;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:67:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double centimeter2 = centimeter*centimeter;
       ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:67:20: error: expected unqualified-id
static constexpr double centimeter2 = centimeter*centimeter;
                 ^
/Users/jeon.hk/Documents/geant4/geant4.10.3-install/bin/../include/Geant4/CLHEP/Units/SystemOfUnits.h:68:10: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
static constexpr double centimeter3 = centimeter*centimeter*centimeter;
       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
scons: *** [build/macosx64/rat.o] Error 1 
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I'm really thanks for any comment.

Comment: Looks like you are compiling using C++ 2003, instead of C++ 11 or up. Can you show how you are invoking the compiler?

Comment: constexpr was added in c++11. `clang++` default to an older standard (c++98 or c++03).  you need to use `clang -std=c++11` (or `-std=c++14`).

Comment: @Frank - I'm just using command "./configure" and " make -j2"

Comment: @KelvinSherlock - How can use that command "clan -std=c++11" in my "scons" command?

Comment: try `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 scons` or `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 ./configure`

Comment: The above CXXFLAGs trick also work with npm. Thanks! In my case I wanted to install OpenCV and had to run "CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 npm i -g opencv4nodejs"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Correct answer to this problem is to compile with c++11 support enabled ( for clang `-std=c++11` )  in order to have the constexpr keyword recognized.

Comment: For those who use VS-Code debug. Add `"-std=c++11",` to the start of your `args` array in your `cppbuild` task in `.vscode/tasks.json`