CMake: including assimp header files and linking to shared library
I am trying to include the assimp library to import models. When I went to compile the code using CMake I got a series of errors. I followed the build instructions to build a dynamic library on Assimp's Repo and put the compiled library in a lib folder, as well as the assimp header files in my include directory.
My CMakeLists.txt is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
project(app)

# set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

find_package(glfw3 3.4 REQUIRED)
set(SOURCES main.cpp glad.c shader.h camera.h stb_image.h mesh.h model.h)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
# link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
# ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
# ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/glad/include
# ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GLFW/include
# ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/glm/include
# ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/assimp/include
# )



add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libassimp.a)

and my project structure is
Project Directory:

CMakeLists.txt
source files
include:

assimp
other includes


lib:

libassimp.5.4.1.dylib



The errors occur when I run make and I don't get any errors when running cmake
How can I fix my CMakeLists.txt to properly include the compiled assimp library and link to to my project?
I have tried changing my CMakelists.txt to use target include directories, before and after the add_executable line (after research I know it has to go after now), as well as attempting to use a static library target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libassimp.a) with no luck.
I have run into the same problem trying to include ImGui and tried to use GLOB with no success.
I have deleted my CMakeCache and build-files after each change.
ERRORS:
This is the first two errors I get when I run make:
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/main.cpp:11:
In file included from /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/model.h:9:
In file included from /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/include/assimp/Importer.hpp:58:
In file included from /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/include/assimp/types.h:61:
/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/include/assimp/defs.h:292:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr ai_real ai_epsilon = (ai_real) 1e-6;
^
/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/include/assimp/defs.h:292:18: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
constexpr ai_real ai_epsilon = (ai_real) 1e-6;

Linker Failing Error when running make:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -S/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp -B/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build/CMakeFiles /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/depend
cd /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/DependInfo.cmake "--color="
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/build
[ 25%] Linking CXX shared library libassimp.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o libassimp.dylib -install_name @rpath/libassimp.dylib  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/lib/libassimp.5.4.1.dylib 
[ 25%] Built target assimp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/app.dir/depend
cd /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build && /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build /Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build/CMakeFiles/app.dir/DependInfo.cmake "--color="
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/app.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable app
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/app.dir/glad.c.o -o app   -L/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/lib/libassimp.5.4.1.dylib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/aag/Documents/code-projects/testcpp/build /opt/homebrew/lib/libglfw.3.4.dylib libassimp.dylib 
ld: Undefined symbols:
  Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int), referenced from:
      Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned int) in main.cpp.o
  Assimp::Importer::Importer(), referenced from:
      Model::loadModel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) in main.cpp.o
  Assimp::Importer::~Importer(), referenced from:
      Model::loadModel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) in main.cpp.o
      Model::loadModel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) in main.cpp.o
  Assimp::Importer::GetErrorString() const, referenced from:
      Model::loadModel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) in main.cpp.o
  _aiGetMaterialTexture, referenced from:
      aiMaterial::GetTexture(aiTextureType, unsigned int, aiString*, aiTextureMapping*, unsigned int*, float*, aiTextureOp*, aiTextureMapMode*) const in main.cpp.o
  _aiGetMaterialTextureCount, referenced from:
      aiMaterial::GetTextureCount(aiTextureType) const in main.cpp.o
  _stbi_image_free, referenced from:
      TextureFromFile(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool) in main.cpp.o
      TextureFromFile(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool) in main.cpp.o
  _stbi_load, referenced from:
      TextureFromFile(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool) in main.cpp.o
  _stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load, referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

updated CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
project(app)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libassimp.5.4.1.dylib)

find_package(glfw3 3.4 REQUIRED)


add_library(assimp SHARED ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libassimp.5.4.1.dylib)
set_target_properties(assimp PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set(SOURCES main.cpp glad.c shader.h camera.h stb_image.h mesh.h model.h)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)


We cannot help you to fix your code if we don't know the exact errors. "they are mostly undeclared identifier errors" - If that description is correct, then the problem is probably about conflicts between assimp and your environment and/or other libraries. In that case it is important to know the exact error messages. If you have many errors, then make sure to provide the very first one (and warnings, which precede it).

Okay, thank you. I have added the first few lines of errors, there were no warnings.

Have you tried to search for the first error message about constexpr? This is a keyword introduced in C++11 standard, so you need to compile your project with that standard (or higher): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047508/error-unknown-type-name-constexpr-during-make-in-mac-os-x. See that question about the way how to do that with CMake.

Thank you I set the CXX Standard to 11 at the top of my CMakeLists.txt and that fixed the majority of the errors but now I am getting undefined symbol errors:  ld: Undefined symbols:   _crc32, referenced from:       _unzReadCurrentFile in libassimp.a[215](unzip.c.o)       _unzReadCurrentFile in libassimp.a[215](unzip.c.o)   _inflate, referenced from:       Assimp::Compression::decompress(void const*, unsigned long, std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char>>&) in libassimp.a[4](Compression.cpp.o) is there a specific way to link the program?

Have you tried to search for those messages? E.g. searching for Undefined symbols: _crc32 finds that question.

@Tsyvarev I've tried searching for a variety of different ways to link my program to the .dylib and by using add_library I am now only getting a few ld: Undefined symbols errors. I will add the full verbose output of the linker failing to the end of the question. I can't seem to find a way to link it to my main.cpp.o file

"I've tried searching for a variety of different ways to link my program to the .dylib" - Have you checked that answer or any other answer to the question?

@Tsyvarev Searching for the undefined symbol you suggested as well as the link in your most recent comment lead me to finding I needed to add the ZLIB package which solved my problem, thank you for all your help
